# a simple calculation

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, partial-differential-equations

Can anyone see how (1) lead to (2)? 
\begin{align}
 \int_{\Omega}\{-\Delta(\phi_{\varepsilon}(b^{\varepsilon}))(b^{\varepsilon})^p\}(t)&=\int_{\Omega}\{-\Delta((\varepsilon+b^{\varepsilon})^k-{\varepsilon})^k)(b^{\varepsilon})^p\}(t)\quad (1)\\
 &=\int_{\Omega}\{kp(\varepsilon+b^{\varepsilon})^{k-1}(b^{\varepsilon})^{p-1}|\nabla b^{\varepsilon}|^2\}\quad  (2)
\end{align}
Here 
$$
\phi_{\varepsilon}(s):=(s+\varepsilon)^k-{\varepsilon}^k
$$
$$
\nabla\phi_{\varepsilon}(b)=0
$$
and $\varepsilon$ is a small positive number.

$b\in C(\bar{Q}_T)$, where $Q_T=\Omega\times (0,T]$

Note: The Laplacian applies only to $\phi_{\varepsilon}(b^{\varepsilon})$, not $(b^{\varepsilon})^p$ .

Comment: Could you please specify what kind of function $b$ is? (i.e. domain and codomain)

Comment: I don't get the notation. Is it $-\Delta\phi_\varepsilon(b^{\varepsilon (p+1)})$ or $-\Delta(\phi_\varepsilon(b^\varepsilon)\cdot b^{\varepsilon p})$ or ...?

Comment: have added some clarification

Comment: So you can write $-\Delta\phi_\varepsilon(b^\varepsilon)\cdot b^{\varepsilon p}$, right?

Comment: last question: do you have conditions on $b$, such as for example $b=0$ on $\partial\Omega$?

Comment: $\nabla b=0$. Could you how 59 leads to 60?

Comment: Please add all the information you have into the original post, so people can answer more easily!